# How to use git ssh key behind a jump box?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I visit a gitlab service through a jump box, like

```
local----> jump box ----> server with gitlab service
```

Then I forward the gitlab service to local port

```
$ ssh -L 8888:<gitlab server ip>:8888 myname@<jump box ip>
```

Now I can visit gitlab on browser(http://127.0.0.1:8888) or git http://127.0.0.1:8888/path/to/project.git

But password is need through http method

I've already registered ssh-key on gitlab. How can I use ssh method to git?

---

Here's my .git/config

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@127.0.0.1:8888/path/to/project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Got a `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

```
$ git pull
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 8888
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

```
$ ssh -p 8888 -v git@127.0.0.1  
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ebi/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 8888.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ebi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Server: nginx
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: Date: Mon, 17 May 2021 11:18:50 GMT
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Content-Type: text/html
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: Content-Length: 166
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: Connection: close
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6: 
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 7: <html>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 8: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 9: <body bgcolor="white">
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 10: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 11: <hr><center>nginx</center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 12: </body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 13: </html>
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 8888
```

Comment: Forward the ssh-port and not only the http port of the remote service

Comment: Or configure `ssh` at `local` with [`ProxyJump`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+proxyjump) and change the remote URL to connect to Gitlab. Before using `git` check connection with `ssh -Tv gitlab`

Comment: Note that as far as Git is concerned, there's nothing happening here. Git just *runs* `ssh`. That's all it does. Everything has to be handled *by* `ssh`.